# how to communicate with solr while searching?

Tags: solr

I am learning how to develop a search application using solr.I have a website created using html where it has a search bar.

when the user enters a keywords to be searched it has to retrieve the matched records from data indexed into solr. my question is how to connect frontend 
website with solr.

Please give me clear steps to implement the same.

Answer (score 0):

There are different library for communication with solr, you can use depends on your technologies. some are ::

**Solarium [PHP] :**

Solarium is a PHP Solr client library that accurately model Solr concepts. Where many other Solr libraries only handle the communication with Solr, Solarium also relieves you of handling all the complex Solr query parameters using a well documented API.

https://github.com/solariumphp/solarium

**Haystack [Django] :**

Haystack provides modular search for Django. It features a unified, familiar API that allows you to plug in different search backends (such as Solr, Elasticsearch, Whoosh, Xapian, etc.) without having to modify your code.

https://django-haystack.readthedocs.io/en/master/

Answer (score 0):

If you are using JavaScript you could use the Sorl REST API directly from the client.

There are various client APIs:
https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/client-apis.html